# Module to wrap a class method?

Tags: ruby, module, wrapper

Is it possible to make this work, without having to include the module at the end of the class and just include it at the top?

```
module VerboseJob
  def self.included(job_class)
    class << job_class
      alias_method :original_perform, :perform
      def perform(*args)
        JobLogger.verbose { original_perform(*args) }
      end
    end
  end
end

class HelloJob
  include VerboseJob

  def self.perform(arg1, arg2)
    puts "Job invoked with #{arg1} and #{arg2}"
  end
end
```

What I want to happen, is for `HelloJob.perform` to actually invoke `VerboseJob.perform` (which then calls the original method inside a block).  Because the module here is included at the top of the class, this doesn't work, since `perform` isn't yet defined.  Moving the `include` to the end does work, but is there a way that's a bit more forgiving?  I like to keep all the included modules at the top of my class definitions.

I'm sort of looking for some method that is called on `Module` or `Class` when it has been fully loaded, instead of as it is interpreted by the runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a rather roundabout/hackish way of doing it that I came up with by deferring the definition of the wrapper method until the original method had been defined:

```
module A
  def self.included(base)
    base.class_eval do
      def self.singleton_method_added(name)
        @@ran||=false
        if name==:perform && !@@ran
          @@ran=true
          class<<self
            alias_method :original_perform, :perform
            def perform(*args)
              puts "Hello"
              original_perform(*args)
            end
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end

class B
  include A

  def self.perform
    puts "Foobar"
  end
end

B.perform
```

**Edit:**

d11wtq simplified this to the much cleaner:

```
module VerboseJob
  module ClassMethods
    def wrap_perform!
      class << self
        def perform_with_verbose(*args)
          JobLogger.verbose { perform_without_verbose(*args) }
        end

        alias_method_chain :perform, :verbose \
          unless instance_method(:perform) == instance_method(:perform_with_verbose)
      end
    end

    def singleton_method_added(name)
      wrap_perform! if name == :perform
    end
  end

  def self.included(job_class)
    job_class.extend ClassMethods
    job_class.wrap_perform! if job_class.respond_to?(:perform)
  end
end
```

Comment: Why not just use `method_added` to wrap `perform` when it is.. er.. added? :)

Comment: I'm not sure I get your meaning, am I not doing that?

Comment: I took your answer (combined with this http://pivotallabs.com/users/rolson/blog/articles/1162-redefine-a-method-from-a-module-like-a-gentleman) and came up with the more succinct https://gist.github.com/1170661 (it works no matter where the `include` is done).  Feel free to edit your answer.  I'll accept it anyway :)

Comment: @Tapio: I'm sorry, I misunderstood your code. It's not that hackish IMO.

Comment: @d11wtq awesome, that's much cleaner!

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that you want all of your classes defined before you want `perform` run, you may want to use [Kernel#at_exit](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Kernel.html#M001431):

> Converts block to a Proc object (and therefore binds it at the point
>   of call) and registers it for execution when the program exits. If
>   multiple handlers are registered, they are executed in reverse order
>   of registration.

```
   def do_at_exit(str1)
     at_exit { print str1 }
   end
   at_exit { puts "cruel world" }
   do_at_exit("goodbye ")
   exit
```

> produces:
>
> goodbye cruel world

You may also want to look at how unit testing frameworks, such as Test::Unit or MiniTest, handle delaying the running of tasks.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how this relates to my question, which is about "wrapping" a class/instance method from inside an included Module?

Comment: @d11wtq: I'm trying to solve the problem that you have in the most appropriate manner. See [Describe the goal, not the step](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#goal)